# How to take atan2 to dy/dx using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to calculate the angle of the tangent for a curve to horizontal. I'm using sympy and have the function differentiated.

```
x = symbols('x')
y = (0.5 * (K_inv) * (exp(K * x) + exp(-K * x))) - K_inv
diff_y = diff(y)
f_diff = lambdify(x, diff_y)
theta = atan(f_diff(x_h))
```

but I get values outside of what makes sense for my application. So I wanted to instead use `atan2`, but how do I do that properly now that I have to define dx and dy explicitly since `atan2` requires two arguments?

Comment: what is K and K_inv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace your last statement in this way:

```
theta = atan2(f_diff(x_h) * x_h, x_h)
```

This will return an angle measured in radiants in the range (-pi, pi].

I'm not going through the math behind this unless you *really* need it, as I think this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I dunno why I didn't realize that. Thank you very much